Logseq advanced (but simple) query
In logseq I am not able to create a query that returns blocks with start property (a date in [[Journal Date format]]) in the last 10 days.
What am I doing wrong? the following code seems to extract all the blocks but does not apply the time filter
#+BEGIN_QUERY
{   :title "Last 10 days activities"
    :inputs [:-10d :today]
    :query [
        :find (pull ?b [*])
        :in $ ?start ?stop
        :where
           [?b :block/properties ?prop]
           [(get ?prop :start) ?daystarted]   
           [(and (> ?daystarted ?start) (< ?daystarted ?stop))]
     ]
}
#+END_QUERY

